# Face Landmarks and stabilization using optical flow

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I write program when window show face and some special points(68). 
I use Haar casscade and FaceLandmarkLBF.I have problem in my program. When face have stable position face points are jitter(shaking). How I can fix that? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

#include <opencv2/face.hpp>

using cv::Scalar;
using cv::Point;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::CascadeClassifier faceDetector("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");

    cv::Ptr<cv::face::Facemark>facemark = cv::face::FacemarkLBF::create();

    facemark->loadModel("lbfmodel.yaml");

    cv::VideoCapture vc(0);

    while (true)
    {
        cv::Mat frame, gray;

        vc.read(frame);

        cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        //
        std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;

        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);

        std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point2f> > landmarks;

        bool success = facemark->fit(frame, faces, landmarks);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < landmarks.size(); i++)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < landmarks[i].size(); j++)
            {
                cv::circle(frame, cv::Point(landmarks[i][j].x, landmarks[i][j].y), 2, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
            }
        }
        cv::imshow("1", frame);

        if ((char)cv::waitKey(20) == 27)
            break;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I saw @Nuzhny link : [lkdemo.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp). Not everything is clear for me.
I done rewrite my code but nothing changed:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"

#include <opencv2/face.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::CascadeClassifier faceDetector("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");

    cv::Ptr<cv::face::Facemark>facemark = cv::face::FacemarkLBF::create();

    facemark->loadModel("lbfmodel.yaml");

    cv::VideoCapture vc(0);

    cv::Mat gray, prevGray, image, frame;
    cv::Size subPixWinSize(10, 10), winSize(64, 64);
    cv::TermCriteria termcrit(cv::TermCriteria::COUNT | cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 20, 0.03);
    std::vector<uchar> status;
    std::vector<float> err;

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> oldLandmarks;
    std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point2f> > landmarks;

    bool b = true;
    while (true)
    {

        vc.read(frame);

        cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;

        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);

        bool success = facemark->fit(frame, faces, landmarks);

        if (!success)
        {
            cv::imshow("1", frame);
            continue;
        }
        if (oldLandmarks.empty())
            oldLandmarks = landmarks.front();

        if (prevGray.empty())
            gray.copyTo(prevGray);

        calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevGray, gray, landmarks.front(), oldLandmarks, status, err, winSize, 3, termcrit, cv::OPTFLOW_LK_GET_MIN_EIGENVALS, 0.001);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < oldLandmarks.size(); i++)
        {
            cv::circle(frame, cv::Point(oldLandmarks[i].x, oldLandmarks[i].y), 2, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
        }

        cv::imshow("1", frame);

        std::swap(oldLandmarks, landmarks.front());
        cv::swap(prevGray, gray);

        if ((char)cv::waitKey(20) == 27)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We had a limited success with applying a Kalman filter to each point's movement. But I also wonder very much what would be a better, more suitable alternative.

Comment: @AMA, how I can use Kalman filter for points?

Comment: I don't have the solution. You would use landmark detector output as new measurements for the state. I've also found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rLohXlOjgI). In the comments the author explains that he uses some sort of weighted average between optical-flow tracker and landmark detector. Tracker is trusted more for the smaller motions.

Comment: @AMA, I see author use `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` but I can't unserstand what is `InputArray prevImg, InputArray nextImg, InputArray prevPts, InputOutputArray nextPts`...

Comment: Optical flow - good idea: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp

Comment: Can you attach the current output where points jitter? in a GIF or some video format?

Comment: Do you see jitter when drawing the face bounding box alone? Variation in initial bounding box could be one reason. Other is, it's typically more convenient to draw landmarks as line segments instead of too much worrying individual points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only LK tracking may be not enough. I'm writing some simple application for correcting landmarks after LK with linear Kalman filter (**EDIT 2** - remove prev landmarks):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/face.hpp>

///
class PointState
{
public:
    PointState(cv::Point2f point)
        :
        m_point(point),
        m_kalman(4, 2, 0, CV_64F)
    {
        Init();
    }

    void Update(cv::Point2f point)
    {
        cv::Mat measurement(2, 1, CV_64FC1);
        if (point.x < 0 || point.y < 0)
        {
            Predict();
            measurement.at<double>(0) = m_point.x;  //update using prediction
            measurement.at<double>(1) = m_point.y;

            m_isPredicted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            measurement.at<double>(0) = point.x;  //update using measurements
            measurement.at<double>(1) = point.y;

            m_isPredicted = false;
        }

        // Correction
        cv::Mat estimated = m_kalman.correct(measurement);
        m_point.x = static_cast<float>(estimated.at<double>(0));   //update using measurements
        m_point.y = static_cast<float>(estimated.at<double>(1));

        Predict();
    }

    cv::Point2f GetPoint() const
    {
        return m_point;
    }

    bool IsPredicted() const
    {
        return m_isPredicted;
    }

private:
    cv::Point2f m_point;
    cv::KalmanFilter m_kalman;

    double m_deltaTime = 0.2;
    double m_accelNoiseMag = 0.3;

    bool m_isPredicted = false;

    void Init()
    {
        m_kalman.transitionMatrix = (cv::Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
            1, 0, m_deltaTime, 0,
            0, 1, 0, m_deltaTime,
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1);

        m_kalman.statePre.at<double>(0) = m_point.x; // x
        m_kalman.statePre.at<double>(1) = m_point.y; // y

        m_kalman.statePre.at<double>(2) = 1; // init velocity x
        m_kalman.statePre.at<double>(3) = 1; // init velocity y

        m_kalman.statePost.at<double>(0) = m_point.x;
        m_kalman.statePost.at<double>(1) = m_point.y;

        cv::setIdentity(m_kalman.measurementMatrix);

        m_kalman.processNoiseCov = (cv::Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
            pow(m_deltaTime, 4.0) / 4.0, 0, pow(m_deltaTime, 3.0) / 2.0, 0,
            0, pow(m_deltaTime, 4.0) / 4.0, 0, pow(m_deltaTime, 3.0) / 2.0,
            pow(m_deltaTime, 3.0) / 2.0, 0, pow(m_deltaTime, 2.0), 0,
            0, pow(m_deltaTime, 3.0) / 2.0, 0, pow(m_deltaTime, 2.0));


        m_kalman.processNoiseCov *= m_accelNoiseMag;

        cv::setIdentity(m_kalman.measurementNoiseCov, cv::Scalar::all(0.1));

        cv::setIdentity(m_kalman.errorCovPost, cv::Scalar::all(.1));
    }

    cv::Point2f Predict()
    {
        cv::Mat prediction = m_kalman.predict();
        m_point.x = static_cast<float>(prediction.at<double>(0));
        m_point.y = static_cast<float>(prediction.at<double>(1));
        return m_point;
    }
};

///
void TrackPoints(cv::Mat prevFrame, cv::Mat currFrame,
const std::vector<cv::Point2f>& currLandmarks,
std::vector<PointState>& trackPoints)
{
    // Lucas-Kanade
    cv::TermCriteria termcrit(cv::TermCriteria::COUNT | cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 30, 0.01);
    cv::Size winSize(7, 7);

    std::vector<uchar> status(trackPoints.size(), 0);
    std::vector<float> err;
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> newLandmarks;

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> prevLandmarks;
    std::for_each(trackPoints.begin(), trackPoints.end(), [&](const PointState& pts) { prevLandmarks.push_back(pts.GetPoint()); });

    cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevFrame, currFrame, prevLandmarks, newLandmarks, status, err, winSize, 3, termcrit, 0, 0.001);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < status.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (status[i])
        {
            trackPoints[i].Update((newLandmarks[i] + currLandmarks[i]) / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            trackPoints[i].Update(currLandmarks[i]);
        }
    }
}

///
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::CascadeClassifier faceDetector("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");

    cv::Ptr<cv::face::Facemark> facemark = cv::face::FacemarkLBF::create();    

    facemark->loadModel("lbfmodel.yaml");

    cv::VideoCapture cam(0, cv::CAP_DSHOW);

    cv::namedWindow("Facial Landmark Detection", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);

    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::Mat currGray;
    cv::Mat prevGray;

    std::vector<PointState> trackPoints;
    trackPoints.reserve(68);

    while (cam.read(frame))
    {
        std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
        cv::cvtColor(frame, currGray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(currGray, faces, 1.1, 3, cv::CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT);

        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> landmarks;

        bool success = facemark->fit(frame, faces, landmarks);

        if (success)
        {
            if (prevGray.empty())
            {
                trackPoints.clear();

                for (cv::Point2f lp : landmarks[0])
                {
                    trackPoints.emplace_back(lp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (trackPoints.empty())
                {
                    for (cv::Point2f lp : landmarks[0])
                    {
                        trackPoints.emplace_back(lp);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    TrackPoints(prevGray, currGray, landmarks[0], trackPoints);
                }
            }

            for (const PointState& tp : trackPoints)
            {
                cv::circle(frame, tp.GetPoint(), 3, tp.IsPredicted() ? cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255) : cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), cv::FILLED);
            }

            for (cv::Point2f lp : landmarks[0])
            {
                cv::circle(frame, lp, 2, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), cv::FILLED);
            }
        }

        cv::imshow("Facial Landmark Detection", frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(1) == 27)
            break;

        prevGray = currGray;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, the margenta points - raw landmarks and green points - corrected after LK+Kalman: [result video](https://youtu.be/2LGgo_H3qq0).

You can change Kalman options with 2 constants:

```
double m_deltaTime = 0.2;
double m_accelNoiseMag = 0.3;
```

It's latency and noise.

Comment: Do you get overshooting because of the Kalman filtter (e.g., when quickly moving point suddenly stops)? Could you show some before/after examples?

Comment: Yes. And I added link to result video.

Comment: Hello, 
When this constructor will get called?
 'PointState(cv::Point2f point)
            :
            m_point(point),
            m_kalman(4, 2, 0, CV_64F)
    {
        Init();
    }' @Nuzhny

Comment: Hi! Inside emplace_back function, it is a modern C++